# Relationship between the Itō formula for a Q-Wiener process and the Itō formula for a cylindrical Wiener process. A question on the trace term

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, operator-theory, stochastic-differential-equations

> *Remark*: Even when this question is about stochastic PDEs, it can be answered by someone who has no knowledge about probability theory or PDEs.

I'm reading [Stochastic Differential Equations in Infinite Dimensions](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642161933) and try to understand the relationship between the [Itō formula for a Q-Wiener process](https://books.google.de/books?id=yqlcgl3KumQC&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=%22Leszek+Gawarecki%22+%2B+%22Theorem+2.9%22+%22be+a+symmetric+nonnegative+trace-class+operator%22&source=bl&ots=xF87nrfyWx&sig=YF0MRLs6XO6BLHVSQjCxg-EkYLM&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiksKbKxJXNAhUFkywKHYlEBvUQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Leszek%20Gawarecki%22%20%2B%20%22Theorem%202.9%22%20%22be%20a%20symmetric%20nonnegative%20trace-class%20operator%22&f=false) and the [Itō formula for a cylindrical Wiener process](https://books.google.de/books?id=yqlcgl3KumQC&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=%22Leszek+Gawarecki%22+%2B+%22Theorem+2.10%22&source=bl&ots=xF87nrfw_y&sig=1i3NfrJmQK1U7Ha82B8Yye1-Yco&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiC3cz-w5XNAhXHESwKHWLXDgIQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Leszek%20Gawarecki%22%20%2B%20%22Theorem%202.10%22&f=false).

Let me introduce the necessary objects and please stay with me even when it's a bit lengthy:

> Let
>
> - $U$ be a real separable Hilbert space
> - $Q\in\mathfrak L(U)$ be nonnegative and symmetric
> - $U_0:=Q^{1/2}U$ be equipped with $$\langle u,v\rangle_{U_0}:=\langle Q^{-1/2}u,Q^{-1/2}v\rangle_U\;\;\;\text{for }u,v\in U_0$$
> - $V$ be a real separable Hilbert space and $\iota\in\operatorname{HS}(U_0,V)$ be an embedding
> - $C:=\iota\iota^\ast$

It's easy to show that $C$ is a symmetric and nonnegative element of $\mathfrak L(V)$ with finite [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class).

> Let
>
> - $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
> - $\left\{B^{(n)}:n\in\mathbb N\right\}$ be a family of independent real Brownian motions on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$
> - $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an orthonormal basis of $U_0$

Then, $$W^{(n)}:=\sum_{i=1}^nB^{(i)}\iota e_i\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N$$ converges in $L^2\left(\operatorname P,C^0\left(\left[0,\infty\right),V\right)\right)$ and its limit $W$ is a $C$-Wiener process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$.

$\color{red}{\text{Warning:}}$ $W$ is called a **cylindrical $C$-Wiener process** on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ by many authors. My reference is [A Concise Course on Stochastic Partial Differential Equations](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540707806?token=prtst0416p) where you can find the definition in [Proposition 2.5.2](https://books.google.de/books?id=Q-JDooJbjCAC&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=%22r%C3%B6ckner%22+%22proposition+2.5.2%22&source=bl&ots=QOm7F0ZT3K&sig=1W5EyAN_DS-mcdKiyixmCzSObBU&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVwobIyZXNAhVBXCwKHc26DIEQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22r%C3%B6ckner%22%20%22proposition%202.5.2%22&f=false).

However, the authors of the book mentioned at the beginning of the question use a different definition of a cylindrical Wiener process and, of course, they use this definition in their statement of the corresponding Itō formula.

**The whole reason for this question is**: I want to use the definition of $W$ given here, apply the Itō formula for a $C$-Wiener process and hope that I end with a formula which is equivalent to the Itō formula for a cylindrical Wiener process. That should be the case, right?

> Let
>
> - $V_0:=C^{1/2}V=\iota U_0$ (and note that $\iota$ is an isometry between $U_0$ and $V_0$)
> - $\Phi:\Omega\times[0,\infty)\to\operatorname{HS}(V_0,H)$ and
>     $\varphi:\Omega\times[0,\infty)\to H$
> - $f:[0,\infty)\times H\to H$, ${\rm D}^2f:[0,\infty)\times H\to\mathfrak L\left(H,\mathfrak L\left(H\right)\right)$ denote the second Fréchet derivative of $f$ with respect to the second variable and $$f^{(n)}:=\langle f,x_n\rangle_H\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N$$ for some orthonormal basis $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of $H$

We consider the equation $${\rm d}X_t=\varphi_t{\rm d}t+\Phi_t{\rm d}W_t\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge 0\;.$$

The crucial part is the trace term in the Itō formula, which we want to apply to find an expression for ${\rm d}f^{(n)}(t,X_t)$. [It is equal to](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1809731/47771) $$\operatorname{tr}\left[{\rm D}^2f^{(n)}(t,X_t)\left(\Phi_tC^{\frac 12}\right)\left(\Phi_tC^{\frac 12}\right)^\ast\right]=\langle\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}{\rm D}^2f(t,X_t)\left(\Phi_tC^{\frac 12}v_k\right)\left(\Phi_tC^{\frac 12}v_k\right),x_n\rangle_H\;,\tag 1$$ where $(v_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is any orthonormal basis of $V$ and ${\rm D}^2f^{(n)}(t,X_t)$ on the left-hand side of $(1)$ is considered as an element of $\mathfrak L(H)$ (which is possible by [Riesz' representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem#the_hilbert_space_representation_theorem)).

**Question:** Is the right-hand side of $(1)$ actually equal to the trace term in the mentioned Itō formula for a cylindrical Wiener process? Maybe we can further simplify the right-hand side. I'm not sure how I can use the fact that $C^{1/2}=C$ is the orthogonal projection. I could imagine that the sum on the right-hand side is equal to $$\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}{\rm D}^2f(t,X_t)\left(\Phi_t\tilde v_k\right)\left(\Phi_t\tilde v_k\right)\;,$$ where $(\tilde v_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is any orthonormal basis of $V_0$.

---

$\mathfrak L(A,B)$ and $\operatorname{HS}(A,B)$ denote the space of bounded, linear operators and [Hilbert-Schmidt operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator) from $A$ to $B$, respectively. Moreover, $\mathfrak L(A):=\mathfrak L(A,A)$ and $L^\ast$ denotes the [adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint#Definition_for_bounded_operators_between_Hilbert_spaces) of a bounded, linear operator $L$.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but did you ever figure it out? I'm new to the subject and seems all of the papers I read use $Q$-Wiener and Cylindrical Wiener interchangeably whereas the books define them differently, but afterwards use them interchangeably.

Comment: @Curious Now I'm responding after an even longer period of time to your question, but in case anybody is still wondering: The latter is cause a cylindrical Wiener process on a space $U$ is - actually by definition - a $Q$-Wiener process for a $Q$ on a larger space $U^\ast\supseteq U$, which is most probably the reason why they are being used interchangeable in the literature you've considered.